# Ubuntu installation on old netbook with formatted hard drive

Tags: ubuntu

I have an old HP Intel Atom netbook that wasn't functioning. I formatted the hard drive and wanted to bring it back to life as a linux machine. Unfortunately, when I use the USB boot option, I get:

"Missing operating system. No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key"

I've tried everything, including taking the hard drive out and putting the iso on that, but nothing works. Is there a solution to this or have I created a large door stopper?

> Since you have tried everything, there's nothing left to try. Seriously now: have you checked with another machine that your USB is in fact bootable? Is there a hotkey that allows you to choose boot device on-the-fly, when the netbook starts? If so, is your USB device on the list? – Kamil M.

There is a hotkey and I've set it up, but I just get the "insert boot disk" message. The USB device is on the hotkey list...I believe. There are 3 USB ports and I've tried each one with the same results.

> I don't know which utility you used to set up the bootable USB. But Universal USB Installer always works for me. Give it a try. – andromeda947

That only works on Windows machines. I created the USB using a a mac.

Answer (score 0):

This question is for Askubuntu.
First you need to tell us the model of the laptop, the linux version that you are using and to post a screenshot of your BIOS options, so we can see have you set the BIOS properly. If this is a UEFI based system, you need to change the settings for the flash drive to be detected.

If you can post a screenshot with your phone of the boot menu, BIOS menu.
Its possible that the USBs are broken, did you try with a Windows Instalation or with a CD (external CD drive or internal) if you have a drive?

Most likely your BIOS menu is not configured properly.